# not supported between instances of 'int' and 'list' -Python

Tags: python, list, numbers, max

I want to select the maximum of a number and all number in a list. But this have an error below, how can I fix it?

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'list'

a=[2,3,4,5]
max(a[0],0)
```

Comment: `print(max(a[0],0))` will give output `2` not the error you show.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to find a maximum between list members and one more number - use unpacking (*):

```py
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
max(*a, 99)  # prints 99; equals to max(1, 2, 3, 4, 99)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"""
I want to select the maximum of a number and all number in a list.

Given a list "a" and a number. Return the highest number
regardless of if it is in the list or the number.


"""
a=[2,3,4,5]
print(max(max(a), 0))

a=[2,3,4,5]
print(max(max(a), 2))

a=[2,3,4,5]
print(max(max(a), 3))

a=[2,3,4,5]
print(max(max(a), 5))

a=[2,3,4,5]
print(max(max(a), 5))

a=[2,3,4,5]
print(max(max(a), 6))

a=[2,3,4,5]
print(max(max(a), 99))
```

Output

```
5
5
5
5
5
6
99
```